# Can I make a disk image with different defaults writes?

Tags: macos, disk-image

My technology teacher wants to change the location that screen shots are saved to. I know you do that by run this command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/
```

However every year he uses a Mac mini to reimage the computers. Is there a way to have that changed location be part of the new image?

This is in a computer lab, the computers are MacBook Airs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaults writes to property list files. The com.apple.screencapture plist is located at

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist
```

Once you've made the change with defaults, copy this file to the image.

Comment: so I would copy plist file on the computer with the modified location, then paste it on the image? (Not the best way of saying it, but you know what I mean...)

Comment: @LakesideMiners Yes, precisely